# Is there any way to do this more efficiently in PHP?

Tags: php

First of all, sorry for the title, I didn't know how to describe my problem.

I have the following piece of code (simplified).

```
if ($red && $italic)
    echo "<tr class='red italic'>";
elseif ($italic)
    echo "<tr class='italic'>";
elseif ($red)
    echo "<tr class='red'>";
else
    echo "<tr>";
```

Is there a way to simplify this, i.e. not use 8 lines? I know that's not very important but I was wondering if it could be possible.

Thanks!

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari No it does not need a space: https://3v4l.org/ajUEi

Comment: @Rizier123 ugghh okayyys. :X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can "simplify" it.

`echo '<tr' . ($red || $italic ? ' class="' . ($red ? 'red' : '') . ($italic ? ' italic' : '') . '"' : '') . '>';`

If you're not worried about sending an empty class, this can be shrunk:

`echo '<tr class="' . ($red ? 'red' : '') . ($italic ? ' italic' : '') . '">';`

You could write an entire app in one line if you wanted. But should you? Readability is extremely important.

If you're looking to rewrite your code to make it look less repeated, there are loads of options.

This method is the same number of lines as the original but allows you to easily add another class by changing one part

```
$classes = array('red', 'italic');
$used_classes = array();
foreach ($classes as $class) {
    if ($$class) {
        $used_classes[] = $class;
    }
}
echo '<tr class="' . join(' ', $used_classes) . '">';
```

Comment: _But should you?_  BAM! +1 for that ;)

Comment: I thought of that line before but if only `$italic` is true, the resulting code would read `class=" italic"`, not that that's a big problem. And of course readability is most importan.

Comment: Your method using the foreach is great for when there are multiple classes. I didn't think of `join()`, I'm not that familiar with PHP. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like I never accepted this as an answer, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch.

```
$type = 'iandr';

switch ($type) {
    case iandr:
        echo'<tr class="red italic">';
       break;

    case i:
        echo'<tr class="italic">';
       break;

    case r:
        echo'<tr class="red">';
       break;

    default:
        code to be executed here if $type is different to the above cases.
}
```

Personally i prefer using switches rather than if and else statements.

Comment: OP clearly wanted to _decrease_ the number of lines.

Comment: yes i know however this is considered the tidier approach. Do you not agree?

Comment: I get that this is tidier but this is not what I was looking for. Thanks though!